# \u in JavaScript String.raw`template literal`

Tags: javascript, escaping, rawstring, template-strings

How can I avoid `\u` being interpreted as a character escape sequence?

In my JavaScript project I need a string literal of some beginning LaTeX commands. Before I had every backslash escaped (`\\`), but I recently discovered raw strings in JavaScript. It would be great if I could have the *exact* string literal in my source. Unfortunately, there is now an issue in `\usepackage{indentfirst}`. The `\u` is interpreted as a character escape sequence, which of course is not what I intend.  Is there a way to avoid this behavior, or is this simply not the place for `String.raw`?

Abridged code:

```
var title="title", author="author";

console.log(String.raw`
\documentclass{book}

\title{${title}}
\author{${author}}
\date{}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}
\maketitle{}
\tableofcontents{}
`);
```

I got this to work by replacing the offending line with `` `+"\\usepackage{indentfirst}"+String.raw` ``, but of course this is not very clear.

Comment: Hm, `String.raw` is expected to return `"\\u…"`. Are you getting an error, or just the wrong result? What ES6 implementation do you use?

Comment: @Bergi - Had the same suggestion, but it looks like the new es6  unicode escape which let's you do stuff like `console.log('\u{2622}')` will throw an *Unexpected token* error  inside es6 template strings. So only the `\u` is problematic, not `\n` or `\r` and so on.

Comment: @DavidDomain Using it as a string might throw, but using it tagged with `String.raw` it should not.

Comment: @Bergi Just tried it, this works `console.log(String.raw\`Not a newline: \n\`)`, this does not `console.log(String.raw\`Unicode escape: \u\`)`.

Comment: @DavidDomain In which browser? I hope this is a bug - and if not, it probably should be fixed in the spec.

Comment: @Bergi - Chrome. Guess you are right, musst be a bug or a lag of implementation. Funny thing is transpiling with babel will throw an error as well.

Comment: This was definitely a problem with browsers as of July 2017 (when I last checked), but since then, [after this proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-template-literal-revision/), now `String.raw` literals can contain `\u` so there's no longer an issue. The only thing treated as special is now `${`

Answer (score 2):

You could take advantage of the `\u` syntax by replacing the line with `\u005Cusepackage{indentfirst}`, or even just `\x5Cusepackage{indentfirst}`.

`5C` corresponds with `\`.

Another option might be using the dollar sign and curly braces notation for expressions.
`${'\\'}usepackage{indentfirst}`